# How to move only "blocks" and "chainstate" folders on an external USB hard-drive while running Bitcoin Client on connected laptop with Ubuntu?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, blockstream, fibre

I have experience with [secure-copy](https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/how-to-run-a-bitcoin-full-node-on-a-raspberry-pi-b/) and [secure-download](https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/running-lightning-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-raspiblitz/) but how do I move ***only*** the Bitcoin Client "blocks" and "chainstate" folders within the home directory of Ubuntu 18.04 to an external USB hard-drive while running the Bitcoin Client on the connected laptop with limited storage on board?  I'd sincerely appreciate the best-practice or recommended approach for hosting a Bitcoin full-node on a laptop with an external USB hard-drive since I am also attempting to run Blockstream and FIBRE on this environment- thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this according to the [Bitcoin Core Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) is to append the **datadir** option after running `bitcoind` to launch the client [according to the following syntax:](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7gzsgp/change_location_of_bitcoin_core_data/)

- `bitcoind -datadir=/media/myusername/backup/.bitcoin`

example provided thusly:

- `bitcoind -datadir=/media/alexanderjsingleton/SEAGATE/.bitcoin`

Also, don't forget to mount the external USB hard-drive by using the `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` [option by command line](https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/how-to-run-a-bitcoin-full-node-on-a-raspberry-pi-b/) or by [GUI-method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547965/mounting-external-hard-disk-for-all-users-at-start-up-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Unfortunately, this also moves the wallet.dat file to the new location. Not what the OP was looking for, I think...

Answer (score 1):

Also, after bitcoin(d)  link creates the ~/.bitcoin folder, you can add a link to external drive.

```
cd ~/.bitcoin
rm -rf ./blocks
rm -rf ./chainstate
ln -s /data/btc_blocks ./blocks
ln -s /data/btc_chainstate ./chainstate
```

remove original block and chainstate though.

Comment: This is true, but don't forget to copy the blocks and chainstate folders first! These instructions delete the existing data and remap the directories, but then you'd need to do another full "initial block download". (And make sure you stop the bitcoin daemon first)